# R Xpath to be used to avoid a specific ancestor.

Tags: r, xpath

I am working in R to analyze a complex structure of a web, and I want to extract the information that is contained in font tag, but happens to be that the data from tables are as well between font tags.

XPath examples:

```
text/div/font
table/tbody/tr/td/div/font
```

Since the structure is very complex, I can not predict the exact Xpath, so I am using //font as xpath to extract relevant data, but since the information in tables are contained as well in tags font, I am getting information that is not relevant for my analysis.

```
xpathCodefont <- "//font"
htmlCodeFonts <- xpathSApply(htmlCode,xpathCodefont,xmlValue)
```

Is there any syntax that allow me "to skip" the fonts that are coming from a path with tables? Or in other words, how could I avoid fonts that have table as ancestors (but not as direct parent).

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would have been nice to include a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so we could test possible solutions, but I think you want

```
xpathCodefont <- "//font[not(ancestor::table)]"
```

That should return any font tags that are not inside tables.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much, it works.